# Python Dictionary million records process via threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

There is Python dictionary with millions records incremental order that need to be processed by threads.

```
data = {}
data[number] = name
```

The numbers are in incremental order, they go from 1 to 1 million

The threards are called tested via

First option backfires as it only processes certain threads defined by max_tries.

```
for i in xrange(1, max_tries + 1):
    name = data.get(str(i))

    current = MainThread(name)
    check_results.append(current)
    current.start()
```

Second one executes a million records at a time.

```
for item in data:
    name = data[item]

    current = MainThread(name)
    check_results.append(current)
    current.start()
```

How would you solve it.

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary instead of a list? Are some indexes missing? Also, is your code CPU bound or IO bound? Threads in python don't add performance to CPU bound processing. Also, check the `concurrent.futures` module. It works on Python 3 but has a backport on PyPI

Comment: The incremental number in the dictionary are later used.

Comment: How about using a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` to create a sane number of threads and use its `ThreadPool.map` method for processing.

Comment: As with @JBernardo, I'm still not sure why you use a `dict`. If the keys really are 1 through 1000000, then a list would be much more efficient. "they are later used" is still a head-scratcher because a list index can be used later also.

Comment: The incremental numbers from dict are later logged into csv file along with name

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor). I haven't tested the following codes, so please treat them as pseudo codes.

```
import concurrent.futures

def my_processing_function():
    pass

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:

    future_objects = []
    for item in data:
        name = data[item]
        future_objects.append(executor.submit(my_processing_function, name, 60))

    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_objects):
        try:
            res = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('exception: {}'.format(exc))
        else:
            print("Result: {}".format(res))
```